# How to make a floated span and select element fill the width of a table cell

Tags: html, css

I have a table cell as follows in a table:

```
<td>
<span class="subtitle no-select" id="billing-status-span" style="float:left"> Status </span> 
<select id="bill-status" style="float:left">
    <option>One of many options with lots of text and therefore width</option>
</select>
</td>
```

Please advise

For example. Imagine the td is 100px wide  (in fact td width is dynamic as it's percentage based). Because the select width is >100px, how do I handle this? I want the select width to shrink... but notice the option width is forcing the select to be greater than 100px

Comment: Do you mean "how do i make the floated span fill the width of the table cell"?

Comment: No. Imagine the td is 100px wide  (in fact td width is dynamic as it's percentage based). Because the select width is >100px, how do I handle this? I want the select width to shrink... but notice the option width is forcing the select to be greater than 100px

Answer (score -1):

I think there is no need of  tag just for status. You can just 
like

```
<td>Status<select id="bill-status"> <option>One of many options with lots of text and therefore width</option></select></td>
```